# User authentication in Django. Problems with is_authenticated

Tags: django, authentication

I have one problem with users menu. So, I want, that authenticated user can see his/her profile page and logout (links) in menu. It works (when I logging in) on index page: *index, page1, profile, logout* ,but, if I go to the, for example, page1 I can see in menu: *index, page1, login*, not profile and logout. How to fix it?

**in urls:**

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' ),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login' ),
url(r'^accounts/profile/$', 'my_app.views.profile' ),
```

**in views:**

```
def profile(request):
    if  not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/login/")        
    else:
        user = request.user.is_authenticated()
        return  render_to_response('profile.html',locals())
```

**Part of index.html:**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated or request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <li><a href="/accounts/profile/">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/accounts/logout/">logout</a></li>
{% else %}
    <li><a href="/accounts/login/">login</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

**login.html:**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block application %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Try one more time</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**profile.html:**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block application %}
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ request.user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**page1.html:**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block application %}
some for loops here
{% endblock %}
```

**views for page1:**

```
def car(request):
    all_cars = Car.objects.all().filter(active=1).values('id', 'name')
    return render_to_response('page1.html', {'all_cars': all_cars})
```

Comment: `user = request.user.is_authenticated()` - it returns True or False, isn't it? May be, `user = request.user`?

Comment: @madjar, no. @Marboni, `user = request.user` - replace in all files?

Comment: @tim, see my answer. You need to add `context_instance` when render response - it let you use `request.user` in template, not specifying it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to manually pass `user` when rendering the template. Try doing this.

In **view.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

In **settings.py**

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
```

In **index.html**:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li><a href="/accounts/profile/">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/accounts/logout/">logout</a></li>
{% else %}
    <li><a href="/accounts/login/">login</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

In **profile.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block application %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**In page1 view:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# If you want only authenticated users to access this page
@login_required
def car(request):
    all_cars = Car.objects.all().filter(active=1).values('id', 'name')
    return render(request, 'page1.html', {'all_cars': all_cars})
```

> PS: I strongly suggest you to use named urls and use url names instead
>   of hardcoding urls.

Comment: sorry it is django.contrib.auth.decorators

Comment: so, I use your code. When I logging, in index.html (main page) I can see profile anf logout links. But if I go to the 'page1' I see only 'login' link.

Answer (score 0):

Always add `context_instance`:

```
render_to_response('profile.html',locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Even better : use `render` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render).

Comment: in 'if' of profile.html and index.html I use `request.user`. I can logging, but if I go to the another links (page1, etc), I needed logging again